# Unable to retrieve metadata (for ObjectContext)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when add a controller in a mvc razor project then show a error message
how to solve this error message.

**Unable to retrieve metadata for 'pos.Model.Semester'. Unable to cast object of type
'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'**

---

My project Code is

```
public class Semester
{
    [Key]
    public int SemesterId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string SemesterName { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Second Class is:

```
public class SemesterContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Semester> Semesters { get; set; }
}
```

And my Connection String is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-pos-20150527182631;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="pos" connectionString="Data Source=AZIZ;Initial Catalog=PointofSell;User ID=sa; Password=mdazizulhoque.bd1987" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your context class to get connectionstring value

```
public class SemesterContext : DbContext
{
    public SemesterContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        //
    }

    public DbSet<Semester> Semesters { get; set; }
}
```

---

**OR**

if your `mvc versiyon <= mvc4` and your `EF versiyon >= EF6` , then you get error...

Comment: get new error: Unable to retrive metadata for 'pos.Model.Semester'. Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.